# Changing port for unicorn

Tags: port, unicorn, gitlab

I have set up gitlab as described in this tutorial: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/6-4-stable/doc/install/installation.md

Now I need to change the port unicorn is listening to. I have changed the unicorn.rb file. However, unicorn is still trying to connect to the 8080 port.

What am I missing?

Comment: What was the root cause? The unicorn process wasn't properly killed?

Comment: yes - killing it manually did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the logs when restarting Unicorn (as in `log/unicorn.stderr.log`), after changing [`config/unicorn.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/a599d8120ddf4d9a6f66ff0bfbd024e414f38772/config/unicorn.rb.example#L37-L40).

You will see the root cause (like for instance [issue 2236](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2236))

As in [issue 4928](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4928#issuecomment-23497621), make sure unicorn was stopped in the first place (same in [issue 5451](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5451#issuecomment-36510659)).

---

Update Q4 2017 (3 years later)

[Markus Piipari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2875611/markus-piipari) reports in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47369035/6309) using wiht GitLab 10.4 the settings:

```
unicorn['port'] = 8081
gitlab_workhorse['auth_backend'] = "http://localhost:8081"
```

> Then running:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

That should be enough change the unicorn port.