# Gitlab on port 8080

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, debian, gitlab

I'm currently in the process of trying to get Gitlab omnibus installed on my private Debian server, and it works perfectly on port 80, the problem is I also have an Apache server listening on port 80. So I'm trying to get Nginx listening on port 8080 but for some reason I'm getting a 
 "502
Gitlab is not responding" Error
I have edited both "external_url" in gitlab.rb and also the port number under the server block in the nginx.conf file. and no joy.

If someone could help me that would be great!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most likely you have another service listening on 8080, I think the omnibus install have some service hooking 8080 - just use 8081 instead.

**Edit:** I just did a quick search and found that it's the unicorn server that is listening to 8080 with the original omnibus installer.

**Note:** You will only need to change the external_url in gitlab.rb, no other config file should have to be edited for this.

**Edit#2:** As @emeraldjava stated there is an option in the configuration file for using another unicorn port: `#unicorn['port'] = '8080'`

Comment: See the "#unicorn['port'] = '8080'" value in the config file.

Comment: sadly no effect at all with the latest version

Comment: @MarianKlühspies Did you try both options (`#unicorn['port'] = '8080'` and `external_url`)? I'm currently on a few versions old installation so I cannot check if there is any new settings with the latest version.

Comment: Had no effect for me either. Changed `external_url`, `#unicorn['port']`, `gitlab_workhorse['auth_backend']` all to 8081. Still I get errors from Unicorn saying, `adding listener failed addr=127.0.0.1:8080 (in use)`.

Comment: Also tried the suggestion from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011895/gitlab-configuration-issues-nginx-unicorn-port-conflict/32019425#32019425) which involved changing `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/unicorn.rb`. It's true that this generated conf does not have it's port set correctly, however changing it and then restarting (w/o reconf) does not fix the issue. Still 502.

Comment: Finally solved this with two further methods: a) must set `gitlab_workhorse['auth_backend']` and `unicorn['port']` to the same port, but different to the `external_url` port. I'd had all 3 the same. This one was my mistake. b) Went to `var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/unicorn.rb` and commented out the `listen "127.0.0.1:<port>"...` line altogether with ###. This finally resolved the Unicorn port issue. Hope this helps someone. Lastly, the following command is useful for checking which services have claimed a port: `netstat -tulpn | grep :8080`

Comment: @Jansky Yes, unicorn port must be different because it's a whole different service from nginx (web server) which is decided by the port in `external_url`.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this for Gitlab Omnibus (Community Edition, version 10.1.4) by first setting these in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:

```
unicorn['port'] = 8081
gitlab_workhorse['auth_backend'] = "http://localhost:8081"
```

Then running:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

Additionally, if you are running GitLab behind an SSL reverse proxy, you may need to restart that service to get past the cached 502 error page.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with GitLab 13.0, Puma is the default web server and Unicorn has been disabled by default([reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/puma.html)).

so you have to change  following configs in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb :

```
external_url 'http://hostOrDomain:8080/'
puma['port'] = 8081
gitlab_workhorse['auth_backend'] = "http://localhost:8081"
```

Comment: Don't forget to do `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure && sudo gitlab-ctl restart` after doing the changes