# How to change the Gitlab's 8080 port (CE - Omnibus version)?

Tags: git, gitlab

I am now using the Gitlab(omnibus version) to store the source code to my PC.

I would like to change the 8080 port to another port.

To change the 8080 port to another, I try to change configuration file. (e.g. Gitlab.rb(unicorn), Gitlab.yml(nginx)) but server is still run on 8080 port...

How to change the Gitlab's 8080 port to another port?? (e.g. port 9999 ...)

Thank you!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gitlab on port 8080](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320022/gitlab-on-port-8080)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the GitLab settings file `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and set the parameter `external_url` to `http://hostname:9999`.

Don't forget to reconfigure GitLab afterwards: `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

Comment: I changed the port for my external_url and reconfigured but it still tries to listen on 8080.

Comment: To prevent Gitlab from using 8080 all together you will need to change it's unicorn settings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320022/gitlab-on-port-8080. In your gitlab.rb you will need to update `unicorn['port'] = 8080`